# Cannot ping my home machine from an external IP

Tags: networking

I am trying to figure out why I cannot ping my home machine (or router) from an external IP, if I do

```
ping 93.185.29.240
```

100% of the packages are lost. I also did:

```
traceroute 93.185.29.240
```

and got:

```
 1  router1-lon.linode.com (212.111.33.229)  2.705 ms  2.427 ms  2.236 ms
 2  109.74.207.10 (109.74.207.10)  2.110 ms 109.74.207.22 (109.74.207.22)  0.604 ms 109.74.207.16 (109.74.207.16)  1.933 ms
 3  ldn-b4-link.telia.net (62.115.41.64)  3.372 ms ix-ae-13-0.tcore2.ldn-london.as6453.net (80.231.62.149)  1.741 ms  1.617 m        s
 4  ldn-bb3-link.telia.net (62.115.134.134)  1.553 ms ldn-bb4-link.telia.net (62.115.134.138)  1.356 ms ldn-bb3-link.telia.ne        t (62.115.134.134)  4.981 ms
 5  if-ae-17-2.tcore1.l78-london.as6453.net (80.231.130.129)  29.554 ms prs-bb4-link.telia.net (62.115.114.229)  29.370 ms if        -ae-17-2.tcore1.l78-london.as6453.net (80.231.130.129)  29.346 ms
 6  ffm-bb4-link.telia.net (62.115.114.99)  29.265 ms ffm-bb3-link.telia.net (62.115.123.12)  20.259 ms if-ae-3-2.tcore1.pye-        paris.as6453.net (80.231.154.142)  15.222 ms
 7  if-ae-11-2.tcore1.pvu-paris.as6453.net (80.231.153.49)  19.913 ms  19.870 ms  19.795 ms
 8  rostelecom-ic-319651-ffm-b1.c.telia.net (62.115.151.97)  73.235 ms  73.180 ms  73.101 ms
 9  87.226.183.57 (87.226.183.57)  78.962 ms 87.226.181.75 (87.226.181.75)  78.930 ms 195.219.36.34 (195.219.36.34)  61.343 m        s
10  * * 87.226.183.57 (87.226.183.57)  83.506 ms
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

There is 'rostelecom . . .' at position 8 that is my internet provider (and probably 87.226.183.57 is also a providers server), but I do not see my home IP address 93.185.29.240 in the traceroute output. What does this mean?

Should I enable 'ping' in my router settings? Or the packages does not reach the router at all?

**EDIT1:**

I also set up forwarding of port 22 on the router to a local host with IP 192.168.0.103, but

```
telnet 93.185.29.240 22
```

cannot connect.

**EDIT2:**

I can ping my router from a local network:

```
ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.74 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3.33 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=2.14 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=2.77 ms
```

switching 'ignore ping' option on the router ON prevents local ping from being working.

**EDIT3**

```
traceroute 8.8.8.8
```

on my local machine outputs this:

```
 1  _gateway (192.168.0.1)  3.863 ms  3.888 ms  3.882 ms
 2  100.83.176.1 (100.83.176.1)  11.444 ms  25.150 ms  25.156 ms
 3  * * *
 4  188.254.2.2 (188.254.2.2)  20.788 ms  20.769 ms  20.770 ms
 5  92.50.229.138 (92.50.229.138)  25.105 ms 72.14.223.226 (72.14.223.226)  20.758 ms  18.730 ms
 6  216.239.42.53 (216.239.42.53)  25.082 ms 74.125.244.132 (74.125.244.132)  22.785 ms 74.125.244.133 (74.125.244.133)  19.806 ms
 7  209.85.246.61 (209.85.246.61)  29.313 ms 216.239.42.53 (216.239.42.53)  26.783 ms 108.170.235.240 (108.170.235.240)  29.758 ms
 8  209.85.249.173 (209.85.249.173)  33.175 ms 72.14.234.107 (72.14.234.107)  34.899 ms 74.125.253.109 (74.125.253.109)  24.828 ms
 9  172.253.66.108 (172.253.66.108)  32.934 ms 209.85.254.174 (209.85.254.174)  38.215 ms 172.253.51.221 (172.253.51.221)  24.784 ms
10  * * *
11  * * 216.239.63.65 (216.239.63.65)  38.783 ms
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8)  24.026 ms  21.591 ms
```

Comment: Yes, enable ping on your router.

Comment: looks like the ping is enabled on my router, at least a check box 'Safety->Deny (or ignore) Ping-packages from LAN port' is unchecked. My router interface is in Russian, so I am not sure I translated the text correctly.

Comment: @KenJackson I was able to ping my router from the local network, see EDIT1. The router has an option to ignore ping in a DoS protection section, but this option is switched off.

Comment: Google "what's my IP". Can Google and/or other services tell it's `93.185.29.240`?

Comment: Can you also add the output of `traceroute 8.8.8.8` from your local machine?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Checked with Google, https://whatismyipaddress.com and with echo "$SSH_CLIENT" command. They all show the same address.

Comment: @Fanatique see EDIT3

Comment: Last thing I ask.. add the output of `traceroute 93.185.17.28` from your local machine. This way I'll understand if `93.185.17.28` is actually your router, or your router is behind your ISP's router :)

Comment: @Fanatique sorry, we lost the opportunity to investigate this, because the provider made my IP static (and changed something else by the way) and ping along with the incoming connections started to work. So what I can say for sure, it was not router, but the provider.

Answer (score 0):

The provider made my IP static (and changed something else by the way, but I do not know what) and ping along with the incoming connections started to work. So what I can say for sure, it was not router, but the provider.